# How to fix 'ParserGeneratorWarning: 4 shift/reduce conflicts' in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an esolang for fun, and I'm running into some problems with the parser. However, I keep getting the error

> ParserGeneratorWarning 4 shift/reduce conflicts

in my parser.py file.

I'm not quite sure what to do, as I'm fairly new to this area of programming.

```py
    def get_parser(self):
        return self.pg.build()
```

What should happen is that a separate input file should run the command `print(4 + 4 - 2);` which should output to 6, but I just get the error

> ParserGeneratorWarning 4 shift/reduce conflicts return self.pg.build()

Comment: shift/reduce issues are grammar problems

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is that your grammar is functionally ambiguous.  There are four decision points in the grammar at which the parser cannot determine whether to

- reduce a rule's RHS (right-hand side) phrase to a non-terminal symbol
- use the most recent symbol to extend the RHS of another rule.

For instance, you may have rules

```
TERM => constant
TERM => constant + constant
EXPR => TERM + TERM
```

When the parser sees `4` with a look-ahead character of `+`, it doesn't know whether to reduce the `constant` immediately to a TERM (and use the `+` for making an `EXPR`), or to hold it for a longer `TERM`, per the second rule.

Since you failed to post the problematic portion of the grammar, we can't fix your specific problem.  However, looking up shift-reduce errors will help you learn the disambiguation techniques.  Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167751/how-to-solve-a-shift-reduce-conflict) and [here](https://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/srintro.html) for starters.